# the number of equation does not match the number of variables

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages, integral-equations, resolve

Excuse me , can you help me , please ?
When i make run for this programme it give me a wrong that the number of equations does not match the number of variables ,,,, I try a lot on finding the wrong but i failed , for sorry .... can you help me, please ??

```
 F=0.56; w0=2*3.14*4*10^9; wp=2*3.14*10*10^9; e3x=2.25; e3y=2.25; gama=0.012*wp; e3z=1-(wp^2/(w^2+I*gama*w)); m3x=1; m3y=1; m3z=1-((F*w^2)/(w^2-w0^2+I*gama*w)); w=2*3.14*4.5*10^9; c=3*10^8;  ns=1; nf=2; 
    
    m=1;
    k0=w/c;
    hi=Table[i,{i,0.033,0.045,0.01}];
    s=k0*hi*Sqrt[(B/k0)^2-ns^2];
  
    Bvalue=Table[FindRoot[((BesselJ[1+s,k0*hi*Sqrt[nf^2-ns^2]]-BesselJ[s-1,k0*hi*Sqrt[nf^2-ns^2]])/(BesselJ[s,k0*hi*Sqrt[nf^2-ns^2]]))-(2*k3/(k0*Sqrt[nf^2-ns^2]))+m Pi,{B,1.2}],{hi,0.033,0.045,0.01}]
  
    Bvalues=Re[N/.Bvalue]
    BvaluesList=Transpose[{Join[{B},Bvalues]}]
    BGrid=Grid[BvaluesList,Fram->All]
```

Comment: Please fix the code you posted. There are several parts which are syntactically broken.

Comment: @Natas   so sorry but  i can not fully understand you ,,, which is syntactically broken ??

Comment: Your open and closed parentheses do not match. Copy your code above into a notebook and you will see the problem. Also trying to use `N` which is a built-in function as a variable. There are other issues but until you fix the parentheses the definitions are broken.

Comment: @BobHanlon   is it Ok now ??? for N i delete it and want to solve the equation without finding N ,,,, What is the other issues , please ??

Comment: `hi` is a vector so the argument to `FindRoot` has multiple equations; but you are only solving for a single variable `B`. Also in the `FindRoot`, `k3` is undefined. The next two lines make no sense. The last line has `Frame` misspelled.